# Access Properties and Keys within JSON using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, scripting

I have a PowerShell script and would like to access a nested key. Here is my JSON:

```json
{
    "name": "versions.json",
    "versions": {
        "1.0.0": {
            "Component1": "1.0.0",
            "Component2": "1.0.0",
            "Component3": "1.0.0"
        },
        "2.0.0": {
            "Component1": "2.0.0",
            "Component2": "2.0.0",
            "Component3": "2.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm unsure of how to access the values within each version (1.0.0 and 2.0.0). I know I get the property name for each "version" by using:

```bsh
($json.versions.PSobject.Properties) | ForEach-Object {
    "Data: $($_.Name)"
}
```

But how do I iterate through each of a "version" objects properties and view its value, i.e. how do I check what is contained within "1.0.0"? For "1.0.0" I would expect to see

```
"Component1" at 1.0.0
"Component2" at 1.0.0
"Component3" at 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the same you're doing for `versions` for the values of its properties:

```bsh
$json.versions.PSobject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    "Data: $($_.Name)"
    $_.Value.PSobject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        '"{0}" at {1}' -f $_.Name, $_.Value
    }
}
```